# Check if first letter in cell is within provided range in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of companies in column A. I'd like another column to check if the first letter of these companies falls within the range {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"}. I would imagine LEFT would provide the function, if only I could get it to check multiple characters.

For context, I'm nesting the function inside several IFs.

=IF(SEARCH("**",D112),IF(LEFT(A112,1)={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"}," Supplier A-H",IF(LEFT(A112,1)={"i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P"}," Supplier J-P",IF(LEFT(A112,1)={"q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"}," Supplier Q-Z",""))),"")

Answer (score 1):

First create a named range somewhere (I called it `SearchList`) that contains the values "a" through "h". Capitalization is ignored, so no need to include both lower- and upper-case.

Then the test formula is simply:

```
=MATCH(LEFT(A2,1),SearchList,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

`="Supplier "&IF(AND(CODE(UPPER(LEFT(A5,1)))>=CODE("A"),CODE(UPPER(LEFT(A5,1)))<=CODE("H")),"A-H",IF(AND(CODE(UPPER(LEFT(A5,1)))>=CODE("J"),CODE(UPPER(LEFT(A5,1)))<=CODE("P")),"J-P",IF(AND(CODE(UPPER(LEFT(A5,1)))>=CODE("Q"),CODE(UPPER(LEFT(A5,1)))<=CODE("Z")),"Q-Z","Not Alphabetical"))))`

Answer (score 0):

If the list is in column A, enter this into B1 and drag it down:

=IF(LEFT(A1,1)<"I","Supplier A-H",IF(LEFT(A1,1)<"Q","Supplier I-P","Supplier Q-Z"))